# Why does Apollo useQuery hook cause an infinite re-render on error?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-hooks, apollo

I'm using Apollo's `useQuery` hook along with the `graphql.macro` library to load queries from .graphql files. This is in a create-react-app project, so no custom webpack configuration.

The component always starts out in the loading state and works if the network request is successful. However, if the network request is unsuccessful, the component re-renders and retries the request infinitely. The solution is to move the call to `loader` outside of the `useData` custom hook, but why is that? Is the `useQuery` hook internally memoizing requests based on the DocumentNode? If so, why does this only occur in the error state and not when the request succeeds?

**useData.ts**

```
export const useData = (dataID: string = '') => {
  const dataQuery = loader('../graphql/queryData.graphql');
  const { data, error, loading } = useQuery<IData>(dataQuery, {
    variables: { id: dataID },
  });

  return { data, error, loading };
};
```

**component.tsx**

```
export const ViewData: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ dataID }) => {
  const { data, error, loading } = useData(dataID);

  if (loading) {
    return <div>Loading Data...</div>;
  }

  if (error) {
    return (
      <div>
        {`Failed to find data ${dataID}, please check the ID and try again.`}
      <div/>
    );
  }

  const { name, type } = data;

  return (
    <div>
      { `Displaying ${name} of ${type}` }
    </div>
  );
};
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: query should be imported by webpack loader, not in hook body

Comment: This is a create-react-app project, I don't have any custom webpack configurations

Comment: react-app-rewired